# How to label only specific ticks in a base R plot?

Tags: r, plot

How to label only specific ticks in a base R plot? In the following example I would like to plot ten ticks, but only the first and the last one should be labelled.

```
plot(1 : 10, xaxt = "n", xlab = 'Some Letters')
axis(1, at = c(1, 10), labels = letters[1 : 2])
```

[image]

Comment: This is not want I want as it labels all ten ticks.

Comment: Or maybe `axis(1,at = 1:10,labels = c("a",rep("",8),"b"))`?